# Windows 11 - Microsoft RDP Dummy Entries

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11

I use RDP daily, and often have 2 or 3 sessions open simultaneously.

I upgraded Windows 10 to Windows 11 a month ago, and suddenly started seeing a lot of dummy entries (see below). These never stop popping up.

I got tired of this, so I did a clean format of my hard drive, and installed Windows 11 clean.

They continue to happen.

It's not possible I have a virus, this is a work computer, and I have nothing other than developer tools on it. I never use this machine for email or internet browsing.

If I cancel this, it pops right back up. I can never make these go away. If I do 'connect' it, then another guid will pop up. I've experimented, and had as many as 5 or 6 of these going.

From my research, I am the only person in the world seeing this. But that seems unlikely. The machine this is happening on really only has Windows 11, SQL, Visual Studio, Visual Code, and a couple of developer tools. I do not have games or non developer apps installed on this machine.

I've searched my registry and my computer for the guids that are popping up. They cannot be found anywhere. I have no idea where this is coming from. It's unlikely that it's a virus, more likely a Windows 11 bug. But it's just annoying that these keep popping up, and the only option is 'connect'. Like I said, if I hit 'cancel', it comes right back and makes me answer again.
[image: Dummy Entry Example]

I am currently not using RDP. When I look in task manager, I see 2 of them running. This seems odd to me, I don't know why there would be 2 running, when I am not using any.  But there are times I've seen up to 5 lines here, when I am not even using RDP

[image: Task Manager Display]

Comment: I have two Windows 11 Pro machines: One Production, One Insider. Neither have dummy RDP sessions, and also not showing in Task Manager. I will keep watch for a bit, but nothing here.

Comment: This is a bug that is new with Win 11.   I'm a very prolific RDP user, and generally always have a minimum of 2 sessions open, sometimes more.   I never saw this until Win 11.

Comment: No issue here in Windows 11. Report it to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub with screen shots.